# NDK - linking a shared library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to link simple shared library(libhello.so) which I compiled to my native C++ code.
Library libhello.so files are:
1. get13.h

```
#ifndef GET13_H
#define GET13_H
int get13();
#endif
```

2. get13.cpp

```
#include "get13.h"

int get13() {
    return 13;
}
```

Android files are:
1. MyApplication/jni/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_MODULE := libhello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libhello.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := native-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libhello
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

2. MyApplication/jni/Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-24
```

3. MyApplication/jni/libhello.so
4. MyApplication/jni/get13.h - same as the one above
5. MyApplication/jni/native-lib.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
extern "C"{
#include <get13.h>
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_semko_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject asdf) {
    get13();
    return 1;
}
}
```

6. MyApplication/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.semko.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir '../jni'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path '../jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

7. MyApplication/app/src/main/java/com.example.semko.myapplication/MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.semko.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        tv.setText(Integer.toString(stringFromJNI()));
    }

    public native int stringFromJNI();
}
```

The problem is that I get this error during gradle build in file native-lib.cpp:

```
Error:(10) undefined reference to `get13'
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I compiled libhello using android toolchain generated with make_standalone_toolchain.py script which is included in Android NDK package.

Comment: Sorry I've corrected the question

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ndk-build as I use cmake myself, but shouldn't `MyApplication/jni/Android.mk` include all of your `.cpp` and `.h` files in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES `?

Comment: @ahasbini not really, because I'm not trying to compile the library with cpp files. I'm trying to use prebuilt library.

Comment: Ohh correct, sorry missed that point. But then again probably only the `get13.h` file should be included since it's a header file for your shared library defining the methods in `libhello`.

Comment: @ahasbini The get13.h is in the same directory so I don't point to the directory in Android.mk. I'm not sure how I could point the file to the linker.

Comment: Here's a link explaining what I meant: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html, look for section "Exporting Headers for Prebuilt Libraries"

Comment: There's no `extern "C"` in get13.cpp/h, but in native-lib.cpp you're including get13.h within an `extern "C"` block. Are you sure that this isn't causing the linker to think it should be looking for the symbol `get13` rather than `_Z5get13v` (which would be its mangled C++ name)? Do you get the same error if you move `#include <get13.h>` above `extern "C" {`?

Comment: @Michael I tried it this way. Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Did you make sure to rebuild everything, so that it doesn't just try linking the existing object files again? And have you verified that the symbol is indeed exported with the expected name (e.g. using `arm-linux-androideabi-objdump.exe -T libhello.so`)?

Comment: @Michael I'm sure it rebuilds everything. I have not verified. I didn't know that it can be checked. I will check and I'll get back to you

Comment: @Michael I get this line among others `00000000000004ec g    DF .text 0000000000000008  Base        _Z5get13v`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the JNI function itself should be marked as `extern "C"`, like here:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <get13.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_semko_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject asdf) {
    get13();
    return 1;
}
```

If you use **javah** to prepare a `MyApplication/jni/native-lib.h` for you, it will have

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_semko_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject asdf);
```

for you, and in the **cpp** file, you will

```
#include "native-lib.h"
```

and don't need `extern "C"` at all.

To make sure that your **Android.mk** is valid for all architectures, consider this change:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libhello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libhello.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := native-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libhello
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Update**: the important piece is `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` before `LOCAL_MODULE := libhello`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't really call javah, because Android Studio handles that. Do you want me to add #include "native-lib.h" in native-lib.cpp? Because when I do I get "fatal error: 'native-lib.h' file not found". And having the library files depend on native-lib.h is not an option. Unfortunately moving extern "C" does not help.

Comment: You don't need `native-lib.h`. I only wanted to show it as an option. Is the error message same as before? What are the exported symbols of **libhello.so** ?

Comment: The error message is the same. I didn't know that exported symbols could be checked. I'll check and I'll get back to you

Comment: On Mac, I use 
`$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm -D whatever.so`

Comment: One tricky issue could be that you need the prebuilt library (**libhello.so**) for each ABI that you build for your **libnative-lib.so**.

Comment: Ok, so `include $(CLEAR_VARS)` was the answer. Thank you

Comment: Other fixes and comments were also important, it's like the little bagel after soup and steak: without it you still feel hungry, but it was not enough to feed you on its own.